# Expressing Vectors, Finding the Angle and Finding the Area

Tags: calculus, vectors, vector-analysis, scalar-fields

> Part 1
>
> According to the Rectangular solid in the following [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VBbXM.png), express the
>   vectors $\overrightarrow {AF}$, $\overrightarrow {GD}$,
>   $\overrightarrow {FC}$, $\overrightarrow {EC}$ in terms of $\vec a$,
>   $\vec b$ and $\vec c$. M1 and M2 are the midpoints of their respective faces.

$\overrightarrow {AF}=$$\vec a$ + $\vec c$

$\overrightarrow {GD}=$-$\vec a$ - $\vec c$

$\overrightarrow {FC}=$$\vec b$ - $\vec c$

$\overrightarrow {EC}=$$\vec a$ + $\vec b$ - $\vec c$

**Did I express it alright? This is my first exercise and I did not really understand the question when they said EXPRESS. Or should it be expressed in a different form?**

> Find $\overrightarrow {AM1}$ and $\overrightarrow {AM2}$.

$\overrightarrow {AM1}$ = $\overrightarrow {AB}$ + $\overrightarrow {BM1}$ = $\vec a$ + $\frac{1}{2}$$\vec b$ + $\frac{1}{2}$$\vec c$

$\overrightarrow {AM2}$= $\overrightarrow {AE}$ + $\overrightarrow {EM2}$ =  $\vec c$ + $\frac{1}{2}$$\vec b$ + $\frac{1}{2}$$\vec a$

**Again I am not sure about my expression. And is it even correct or did I completely misunderstand the methodology?**

> Form the scalar product $\overrightarrow {AM1}$ ·$\overrightarrow {AM2}$

$\overrightarrow {AM1}$ ·$\overrightarrow {AM2}$=$\frac{1}{2}$($\vec {|a|^2}$ + $\frac{1}{2}$$\vec {|b|^2}$ + $\vec {|c|^2}$)

> Part 2
>
> Using the same image, but let |$\vec a$| = |$\vec b$| = |$\vec c$| =
>   1. Now the  rectangular solid is a cube. Find |$\overrightarrow {AM1}$| and |$\overrightarrow {AM2}$| and then find the angle of it.

|$\overrightarrow {AM1}$| = 1+0.5+0.5= 2

|$\overrightarrow {AM2}$| = 1+0.5+0.5= 2

$\overrightarrow {AM1}$ ·$\overrightarrow {AM2}$= |$\overrightarrow {AM1}$||$\overrightarrow {AM2}$| $cos \varphi$

$\varphi$=71.8

> Find the area of the triangle $\overrightarrow {AM1M2}$.

Area = $\frac{1}{2}$|$\overrightarrow {AM2}$||$\overrightarrow {M1M2}$| $sin \varphi$

**Now here is where I am very confused because I get $0$ for |$\overrightarrow {M1M2}$|. Is that right? But the Area can't be $0$ though...**

*If my answers are wrong I would appreciate it if you'd guide me through my misunderstanding. I missed almost all the classes because I got very sick but I will catch up with some OT*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$AM_1 = a + \frac 12 b + \frac 12 c\\
AM_2 = \frac 12a + \frac 12 b + c\\
AM_1\cdot AM_2 = \frac 12 |a|^2 + \frac 14 |b|^2  + \frac 12 |c|$

If $|a| = |b| = |c| = 1$

$|AM_1|^2 = AM_1\cdot AM_1 = 1 + \frac 14 + \frac 14\\
|AM_1| = \sqrt {\frac {3}{2}}\\
|AM_2| = \sqrt {\frac {3}{2}}\\
\cos \phi = \frac{AM_1\cdot AM_2}{|AM_1||AM_2|} = \frac {\frac {5}{4}}{\frac 32} = \frac 56$

For the area you can say $\frac 12 |AM_1\times AM_2|$

or you can say $\frac 12 |AM_1||AM_2| \sin \phi$

or you can use the Pythagorean theorem to say $\sin^2\phi + \cos^2 \phi = 1$ to find $\sin\phi$

One last note:

${M_1M_2} = \frac 12 a + \frac 12 b  + c - (a +\frac 12 b + \frac 12 c) = -\frac 12 a + \frac 12 c$